# Is there a way to make mobs invulnerable in Minecraft Console Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've tried to find out how to make mobs invulnerable but nothing worked for me.. I'm wondering if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no. You can do it on **PC only** via commands like `/summon <mob> ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1,}`, and I'm pretty sure 4J Studios will never add commands into Console edition in the future.